# can't install bootloader

Tags: windows, boot-loader, ntfs

So I was trying to install BBQLinux. I downloaded the ISO, put it on an USB-Stick, booted from it and used "Install BBQ Linux" on the desktop.

At the end of the installation it gave me this error:

```
Boost.Python error in job "bootloader".
<class 'subprocess.CalledProcessError'>
Command 'grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=bbqlinux --force' returned non-zero exit status 1
Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib/calamares/modules/bootloader/main.py", line 244, in run
    prepare_bootloader(fw_type)

  File "/usr/lib/calamares/modules/bootloader/main.py", line 232, in prepare_bootloader
    install_grub(efi_directory, fw_type)

  File "/usr/lib/calamares/modules/bootloader/main.py", line 182, in install_grub
    "--force"])

  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
```

When I manually tried `grub-install /dev/sda` it gave me this

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

So, I am not sure what to do next.
I guess the problem is, that it can't write at the beginning of the disk. I have a SSD-drive, where there is Windows 10 on the first partition and I tried to install it on the second partition.

My SSD looks like this:

[image]

Is there maybe something, I can do from my Windows OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found out, that the problem was, that I still used Legacy BIOS mode.
I used this HowTo to convert to uefi:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14286.converting-windows-bios-installation-to-uefi.aspx

Then I just installed it again.

Answer (score 0):

The Arch Wiki has outstanding documentation on this subject:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Installation_2

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows#Installation

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Dual-booting

Windows should have already created the EFI System Partition on /dev/sda1, so you shouldn't need to create that.