# Terminal crash during apt-upgrade on ubuntu and now upgrade fails

Tags: ubuntu, grub, upgrade

I was upgrading Ubuntu using

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

But, the terminal crashed in between. When I tried to run the same command again, it gave an error related to lock on dpkg. I deleted the lock files.
Now when I run the command, I get the following error

```
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up shim-signed (1.33.1~16.04.3+15+1533136590.3beb971-0ubuntu1) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: Of course, recognizing the error message in that output would have led to existing Q&As on the subject, including https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320014/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405472/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369748/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265556/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311588/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First confirm whether or not you are running an EFI boot version of Ubuntu.

If you are **not** then:

- This will never work right, because shim-signed is a EFI application.

If you **are** then:

- Make sure your EFI boot directory/partition is properly referenced.
- Then purge shim-signed, `apt-get purge shim-signed` then I would attempt the update and upgrade or reinstall of shim-signed, after a reboot.

You could also try something similar to the following: (change to suit your situation)

- **Be vary sure you know what these commands do and where you want them to place things as doing it wrong will most likely render your system non-bootable.**

  ```
  mkdir /boot/efi
  grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sdX (path to drive where grub is installed).
  apt-get update
  apt-get upgrade
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but how to know if it EFI boot version. This used to work earlier. Only after the terminal crash during the upgrade, it gives this error.

Comment: How to `Make sure your EFI boot directory/partition is properly referenced`?

Comment: Check your fstab and see if you have a boot/efi entry if so good, if not do the following: Check to make sure the directory actually exists on the system ( /boot/efi ) if so good. If your system has both in place other things are amiss. If you have neither then look into why? Also check the permissions of the directory.